# Squats and strange looking knees

Tags: squats

I'm a small guy, but I can put up decent weight on squats.  My lower body is stronger than my upper body.  Since I started squats (a long time ago), my legs looks strange to some people.  Just diagonally upward (and inside) of my kneecaps are bulges (lower quadriceps, I guess) that look sort of like second kneecaps.  They're actually more prominent than my real kneecaps.

What I'd like to know is: is this normal?  Is it possible I've been doing squats with the wrong form this whole time (and quadriceps are taking more load than they're supposed to, for example)?  I don't worry about how my legs look - I just want to be sure I'm doing the exercise right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perfectly normal.

This is the vastus medialis, which is part of the quadriceps muscle group. If you have good definition of your quadriceps, it will/can bulge out on it's own and give the appearance of an extra knee.

Clinical diagram:

[image]

Actual people shot (Competitive bicyclists):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is comforting - my knees look almost exact the same as those of the guy on the left.  Though this pic does make me feel inferior in other ways...

Comment: @horsehair - Me too. I was a competitive cyclist/triathlete for a long time, and I never got much past the guy on the left either. I *think* these are track cyclists, you don't see this much development in road racers typically.